# PDFsharp: How to find the Size dimensions of all the pages in a PDF file?

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I am using PDFsharp, a great tool for working with PDFs.
I am writing an application in VB.net to work with PDFs for the printing industry. I need to know how to find out the dimensions of each page of the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all pages in the PDF and query the page size for each page.

Use the `Pages` property of the `PdfDocument` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetPDFMetaData(ByRef pSourceFile As OpenFileDialog)
    Dim lpdfDocument As PdfDocument = PdfReader.Open(pSourceFile.FileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import)
    Dim lpdfpage As PdfPage
    Dim Text As String = ""
    Dim Width As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer

    For idx As Integer = 0 To lpdfDocument.PageCount - 1
        lpdfpage = lpdfDocument.Pages(idx)
        Width = lpdfpage.Width.Millimeter
        Height = lpdfpage.Height.Millimeter
        Text = Text & vbCrLf & "Page: (" & idx + 1 & "); Size =(" & Width & " X " & Height & ")"
    Next
    Return Text
End Function
```